# Django ошибка при запуске проекта

Tags: python, django

Плиз хелп не получается запускать Django с urls.py

**ОШИБКА**

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/User/Desktop/untitled/untitled/urls.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/untitled/untitled/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 224, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 537, in _setup
    AdminSiteClass = import_string(apps.get_app_config('admin').default_site)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 153, in get_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 134, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 57, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Process finished with exit code 1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавили свое приложение в INSTALLED_APPS в файле settings.py?

Comment: Да я добавил по моему.

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082128/improperlyconfigured-you-must-either-define-the-environment-variable-django-set/28297987

Answer (score 0):

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Jones'
     ]
```